# Get the default link configuration gcc uses when calling the linker

Tags: gcc, linker, arm

I am using the CodeSorcery arm-eabi-gcc tool chain and I have a problem using ld separate from gcc

I can compile my simple program and link it, if I let `gcc` call the `ld`.

This works not problem

```
g++ test.cpp; # Works
```

This does not work because of missing symbols

```
g++ -c test.cpp

ld -o test crti.o crtbegin.o test.o crtend.o crtn.o -lgcc -lc -lstdc++; # Fails
```

Notice I am adding the gcc libraries to the `ld` command

What am I missing?

Also if there is a better way to make configuring ld to using the default `gcc` linking?

Comment: You may answo want to have a look at using spec files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7505529/895245

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to have gcc/g++ drive a separate link:

```
g++ -c test.cpp      # compile
g++ -o test test.o   # separate link
```

If you need to pass linker options, you can use `-Wl`:

```
g++ -o test test.o -Wl,-somelinkeroption,arg
```

Answer (score 4):

@R Samuel Klatchko has the best advice, but if you really want to see what gcc/g++ is linking in use the `-v` [verbose option](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_75.html).

> It displays the full directory paths used to search for header files and libraries, the predefined preprocessor symbols, and the object files and libraries used for linking.