# GCC how to add before the default linker search path by default? LIBRARY_PATH not working

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, ld

I'm trying to figure out how to set some environment variable which would make g++ to link to correct versions of the libraries.

I have some old boost libraries in /usr/lib64 (linking against these will fail) and new libraries in /v/users/regel/lib. So the linker should link against the new libraries.

Command:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -lboost_system -L/v/users/regel/lib
```

links the program correctly. However, I wish to set this as the number 1 search directory for the linker so that I don't have to specify '-L' every time I link.

The following environment variables do not seem to do the trick:

```
$ LIBRARY_PATH=/v/users/regel/lib g++ test.cpp -lboost_system
/tmp/regel/cc4SmBtI.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/v/users/regel/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH g++ test.cpp -lboost_system
/tmp/regel/ccUreBZy.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Despite reading numerous articles and posts on similar subjects, I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Have you tried setting + exporting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running g++ (instead of providing it on the g++ command line) ?

Comment: I have tried exporting both LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running g++.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, setting it the way the OP did has the same effect as exporting it (but limited to that command and its children) so that's not going to help

Comment: Possible same, except no mention of `LIBRARY_PATH` not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726993/g-how-to-specify-preference-of-library-path You may also want to have a look at spec files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7505529/895245

Comment: I wondering if you face the problem during runtime linking on the same system you compiled the binary. The -L option does not stop linker from linking the system library first before it during runtime. -rpath seem to be better option for you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the GCC manual [says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables), `LIBRARY_PATH` is the correct environment variable to add directories to the library search path.

If you add `-v` to the `g++` command you should see the `LIBRARY_PATH` that it uses, and you should see it includes the directory you have specified, and that it gets added to the `collect2` command as `-L`, but you will see it gets added *after* the standard directories such as `-L/usr/lib` etc.

I don't know any way to make the directories in `LIBRARY_PATH` come first, I think you have to use `-L` for that.

Comment: Why was this the accepted answer? It does not answer the question.

Comment: This answer is very helpful because it explains why you cannot do what OP was asking, and what I've been trying to do as well. I'm not happy having to change my Makefiles, but at least now I know why the environment variables don't work.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. The standard gcc installation in Ubuntu puts LIBRARY_PATH first. If you compile gcc yourself, LIBRARY_PATH comes last.

Comment: @facetus I've just tested on Ubuntu versions 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04, and they all put the `-L` dirs first, and the `LIBRARY_PATH` dirs at the end. I don't know why we're seeing different results.

Comment: It looks like debian's gcc puts some paths _based on_ `LIBRARY_PATH` dirs at the start, e.g. with `LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/env gcc -print-search-dirs` I see `libraries: =/tmp/env/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/tmp/env/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/tmp/env/../lib/:...` and _if those exist_ they'll get passed to `ld` first, but it still adds `-L/tmp/env` itself near the end, after the dirs named with `-L`

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the library path in a .conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

The linker looks at paths specified in files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ while linking.

Make sure you run 'ldconfig' once you create the file, that will force it to update its cache.

Comment: I believe you are talking about the loader (ld.so) and not the linker (ld).

Comment: Why this answer is so much "minused"? When I am doing strace on gcc binary, I can see /etc/ld.so.conf file is read (which usually includes ld.so.conf.d/*.conf).

Comment: I think both the loader and the linker look at this configuration, only the linker intended for cross-compilation will not.