# Running a function type of program when the C header file is in a flashdrive?

Tags: c, usb, header-files, turbo-c, usb-flash-drive

Im currently working on C, and would like to know if its possible to run a program when a user made header file is in a flashdrive. It works if the file is on a PC, but not sure if it would if its external.

The code looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<Conio.h>
#include"headerfilewhichcontainsintcheck.h"
void main(){
int a,g,c;    
printf("Input age: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("Input gender: ");
scanf("%d", &g);
c=check(a,g)//the function which will process the variables below, which is, contained in the header file//
getch();
}
```

Again, it runs when the header file is in the PC, but ceases to when its on a flashdrive. Is there something Im missing here? Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried entering the full path of the header file?

Comment: What crashes? The compiler?

Comment: You should add flashdrive link path while compiling. Check [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836423/gcc-how-to-add-before-the-default-linker-search-path-by-default-library-path-no)

Comment: So something like `#include"\\path_to_flashdrive\dir_of_ headerfile\headerfilewhichcontainsintcheck.h"`

Comment: @Mayur the "D:\filename.h"? Yeah I did it still doesn't work. I don't think Turbo C can read external files...

Comment: Do you have read permission for that file?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out all I had to do was to open the DOSBOX and mount the directory, or set path.

mount b: e:\

Anyways thanks for helping I appreciated all of your help...!